# Uniqueness of a Contour Integral

Tags: contour-integration, laurent-series

Is the result of a contour integral around a closed loop path unique?  I'd think it'd be similar to a definite integral, which is unique.

This came up regarding the proof of uniqueness of a Laurent Series - if the contour integral is unique, then the definition of the Laurent Series can be used to prove its uniqueness.

Edit - as pointed out below, the Laurent Series aspect may be a limiting case, as it's within a specified annulus, so for any of the Cauchy coefficients, the same analytic annulus is used, so the same number of poles will always be within the inner radius.

Comment: What is your definition of a contour integral, that makes you doubt it is unique?

Comment: The fact that indefinite integrals do not have a unique solution made me wonder about this case.  If though the path (or set of paths) is specified then this appears to be more analogous to a definite integral.

Comment: The other thing that made me wonder is that none of the proofs of uniqueness of the Laurent Series I've found take this approach.  This approach seems facile - it's unique because the definition makes it unique.

Comment: Contour integrals are definite integrals. I think you’re really asking: “are contour integrals well-defined?” In which case (a) the answer is yes (b) you should tell us what definition you’re using and why you think it might not be well defined

Answer (score 1):

If you are inegrating a function witth pole(s) around a closed loop, the inegral depends on which pole(s) is/are enclosed by the loop.

Comment: (working this out in my head while I type) The definition of the Laurent Series assumes an annulus around a point.  It assumes that the function is analytic within the annulus, however, the center point and/or others inside the inner radius may be poles.  In this case, the contour integral would always encompass the same number of poles.  That does limit my initial question to more a more specific case.